# Driver based on shading types/ change boolean when switching shading types

Tags: python, scripting, interface, drivers

I have a Boolean property in my custom panel that I would like to either use a driver or can I use python to do make my option true/false Based on the shading type. I have searched up what I want, but the answers don't help and I am asking again because those were based on older blender versions.

For example,
When I go into solid shading mode, Visibility of a object is set to hidden and vice versa for other shading types.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Do you want to use this Boolean in a driver, or do you want a driver that sets its value?

Comment: @MartyFouts sorry i will edit that to make sense

Comment: @MartyFouts I edited my post, check whether you can understand my post now.

Comment: Yes, I can.  What you want can be done, I think.  I'll try to put together an answer as soon as I have some time.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my stupid questions

Comment: It's not a stupid question.  I'm finding it a bit tricky in fact, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically run a script when an object is transformed or a condition is met](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249809/automatically-run-a-script-when-an-object-is-transformed-or-a-condition-is-met) Checking the property before/after each frame is rendered is probably the easiest solution. Msgbus typically is the hardest solution - I wonder if someone investigated performance gains of msgbus way...

Comment: As for a driver solution, it's enough to right-click on the "viewport display" icon in the outliner, "Copy as new driver", then right-click on the driven property "paste driver" - except the driver won't update immediately when you click on an icon to disable viewport visibility, it will only update if you e.g. keyframe the viewport visibility and play the animation.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  It doesn't answer the question because material preview mode changes don't happen during renders, they happen during when rendering isn't happeing.

Comment: @MartyFouts Aaah, I understand now. I think the solution would be to use `SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add` in the 2nd part of my answer: [If you don't want it for an animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248048/60486)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady the downside of draw handler is that it gets called very frequently so it's slow compared to a msgbus based solution.

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes, but it [doesn't matter](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/252055/60486)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133600/discussion-between-marty-fouts-and-markus-von-broady).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in comments under the question, I think it's a duplicate of:

[Automatically run a script when an object is transformed or a condition is met](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/249809/60486)

Which points to a *Space3DView* draw callback solution:

[Use a driver to programmatically set the positions of many vertices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248048/60486)

Since we had a conversation in the comments about it, I decided to write an answer here. The principle is the same as under the link (the 2nd part, *"If you don't want it for an animation"*) - on every draw, try to figure out if you don't have to do anything as soon as possible, and in such case just quit the function. That's the purpose of 'last_shading' variable - if you keep track of the last value, you now know if the value changed - if it didn't, you don't have to do anything and you can just quit. The sooner you realize the function has no work to do and can quit, the less CPU cycles you will waste. But, as I show in the [benchmark](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/252055/60486) you don't have to worry about it too much...

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C, data as D
from bpy.types import SpaceView3D

visibility_data = {
    'Cube': {'SOLID', 'MATERIAL', 'RENDERED'},
    'Sphere': {'MATERIAL'},
    'Suzanne': {'SOLID', 'MATERIAL'}
}

last_shading = None


def test():
    global last_shading
    if C.area.type != 'VIEW_3D':
        return
    shading_type = C.space_data.shading.type
    if shading_type == last_shading:
        return
    print(last_shading)  # The lesson from edits... Use a print to inspect if the function isn't executed too often
    for ob_name, shadings in visibility_data.items():
        ob = D.objects[ob_name]
        ob.hide_viewport = shading_type not in shadings
    last_shading = shading_type


try:
    SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(SpaceView3D.my_handler, 'WINDOW')
except (AttributeError, ValueError):
    pass

SpaceView3D.my_handler = SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(test, (), 'WINDOW', 'PRE_VIEW')
```

If you run the script with a project that has a cube, sphere and , all with default names, you should be able to see that they hide automatically based on the `visibility_data` dictionary:

[image]

Not sure if changing the rendering mode updates depsgraph, but for almost anything, consider replacing the view 3D callback with the application handler, as used here by Martynas Žiemys:
[Operator that runs when a value input is changed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274914/60486)

Comment: Thank you for giving an example as well, it helped me understand how to do this. This works.

Comment: There is a tiny issue tho, This seems to run every second which heavily impacts the scene I am working on. is there something like Run once in python?

Comment: @YunethAlwis This runs much more often than once per second, but it doesn't affect the scene in my tests. If you can reproduce the issue in a .blend file you can share, I'll be willing to look into it. Running first 5 lines of the `test` function shouldn't be heavy on CPU even if it's run 100 times per frame. But perhaps there's an error there that causes more work to be done? Could you also tell me what's your hardware you're working on?

Comment: My Hardware is i7 9750H, GTX 1650m.

Comment: @YunethAlwis Your hardware is not an issue then. By "heavily impacts the scene", you mean lowered FPS? It could possibly happen if every time it runs there's an error printed to console... The only idea I can come up with is to add `if not C.area: return` as the first line to the `test` function. Otherwise I'd need to look at your project to find what's the issue.

Comment: I did a test of my own how performance correlates to your code, this is my results i found.

160FPS when code isn't running
100FPS when Code is running

The scene contains 1 million faces with the same setup as you did but with subdiv modifiers.

Also the more geometry you have the more the fps exponentially slows donw with the code.

Comment: @YunethAlwis which code are we talking about? The code in this answer or the code in the linked benchmark?

Comment: The code in the answer

Comment: @YunethAlwis aaah I found the error, mea culpa

Comment: @YunethAlwis see the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/252067/revisions) - that's the crucial part :)

Comment: Thank you Markus von Broady, Very cool :)

Comment: Markus there is a error in the code, UnboundLocalError: local variable 'last_shading' referenced before assignment, this got fixed by putting another = symbol on the new line of code you put, I just wanted to put. thank you:). Is it okay if I can edit your post.

Comment: @YunethAlwis it's getting embarassing... See another [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/252067/revisions)  - this time I tested it and it works.